# XY-pic not sufficiently expressive to draw a simple linked list (data structure)?

Tags: lists, xy-pic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I draw a singly/double linked list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19286/how-should-i-draw-a-singly-double-linked-list)

I am using xypic to draw a linked list. It consists essentially a sequence of chained 2-cell boxes. The problem is how to put array's base-entry inside a box. Something like the diagram below (only one node is drawn here)

Can you tell me how to draw such diagram by xypic pls.? Thanks

```
| ---------|
|  9 |  ------------>
|----------|
```

Comment: If you are willing to try with `TikZ`, here's one possible solution: [How should I draw a singly/double linked list?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19286/3954)

Comment: No, thank. I really prefer to stick to XY-pic.

Comment: The reason I would like to stick to xy-pic is simply because it may take time to learn a new tool like tikz. So let's see the expressibility of xypic.

Comment: May I conclude that xypic is not expressive enough to fulfill this task?

Comment: @zell: I think so. The easiest way is to use TikZ or PSTricks.