# How can I make the path picture bigger?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I draw a singly/double linked list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19286/how-should-i-draw-a-singly-double-linked-list)

I am currently trying to create an image of a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) like this one:
[image]

This is my current try:

[image]

What I miss is the dot at the start of the arrow and the second box for each list element.

This is my try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,arrows,positioning, calc} 

\tikzset{
    squarecross/.style={
        draw, fill=black!20, rectangle,minimum size=18pt,
        inner sep=0pt, text=black,
        path picture = {
            \draw[black]
            (path picture bounding box.north west) -- 
            (path picture bounding box.south east) --
            (path picture bounding box.south west) -- 
            (path picture bounding box.north east);
        }
    },
    listelement/.style={
        draw, fill=black!20, rectangle,minimum size=18pt,
        inner sep=0pt, text=black,
        path picture = {% 
            \draw[black]
            ($(path picture bounding box.north west)$) --
            ($(path picture bounding box.north west)+(1,0)$) --
            ($(path picture bounding box.south west)+(1,0)$) -- 
            ($(path picture bounding box.south west)$);
        }
    }
}

\usetikzlibrary{trees,arrows,positioning, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,very thick]
\node [listelement] (a) {12};
\node [listelement] (b) [right=of a] {99};
\node [listelement] (c) [right=of b] {37};
\node [squarecross] (d) [right=of c] {};
\draw [->] (a) -- (b);
\draw [->] (b) -- (c);
\draw [->] (c) -- (d);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

How can I make it work? Why does the following part not work?

```
path picture = {% 
    \draw[black]
    ($(path picture bounding box.north west)$) --
    ($(path picture bounding box.north west)+(1,0)$) --
    ($(path picture bounding box.south west)+(1,0)$) -- 
    ($(path picture bounding box.south west)$);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've just noticed it. Linked List of course. I've corrected it.

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19288/3954) to [How should I draw a singly/double linked list?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19286/3954) for a solution using multipart rectangles.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't find it, as I've searched for "nested list" instead of "linked list" all the time :-/

Comment: Then we can close it as a duplicate?

Comment: Yes, this topic can be closed. It wasn't directly answered, but the solution is better than a direct answer. - edit: Now it has also been answered. I love this website :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path picture is used to put a picture inside the path region so when you draw something out of the path region they are clipped out. Just to illustrate the scaling

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\tikzset{
    listelement/.style={
        draw, fill=black!20, rectangle,minimum size=5mm,
        inner sep=0pt, text=black,
        path picture = {%
        \pgftransformscale{3}
            \draw[black]
            ($(path picture bounding box.north west)$) rectangle ++(1mm,-1mm);
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,very thick]
\node [listelement] (a) {12};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]