# Creating TikZ Node Using Macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I'm trying to create a linked list using TikZ. I currently have this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes}

\newcommand{chainlabel}[2]{\path [<-, draw, shorten >=10pt] #1 |- node [at end] {#2} ++(-1,1);}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, rectangle split horizontal}, node distance=1em, start chain, 
 every join/.style={->, shorten <=-4.5pt}]

 \node[draw, on chain, join] { 1  };
 \node[draw, on chain, join] { 7  };
 \node[draw, on chain, join] { 5  };
 \node[draw, on chain, join] { 2  };
 \node[draw, on chain, join] {};

 \chainlabel{chain-1.one north}{head};
\end{tikzpicture}  


\end{document}
```

The problem is with the `chainlabel` command. I'm getting all kinds of errors about missing control sequences. I have read somewhere that there needs to be some sort of `expandafter` somewhere but I'm not sure how to work with it.

p.s. The idea behind chainlabel is that we can pass a coordinate to the command and a label and it will label the node with the provided text.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19288.

Comment: Thakns for the link but the linked list isn't the problem here. That I've got working cleanly. The issue is with the label through the command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You had some errors in the definition of your command: you forgot the initial backslash (it's `\chainlabel` instead of `chainlabel`) and, since you used `\path #1 |- ...` the first argument should have parentheses, unless you used `\path (#1) |- ...`, as I did in my example below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes}

\newcommand{\chainlabel}[2]{\path [<-, draw, shorten >=10pt] (#1) |- node [at end] {#2} ++(-1,1);}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, rectangle split horizontal}, node distance=1em, start chain, 
 every join/.style={->, shorten <=-4.5pt}]

 \node[draw, on chain, join] { 1  };
 \node[draw, on chain, join] { 7  };
 \node[draw, on chain, join] { 5  };
 \node[draw, on chain, join] { 2  };
 \node[draw, on chain, join] {};
\chainlabel{chain-1.one north}{head};
\end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps you can add some `minimum height` to the `rectangle split` so even if empty they will have an uniform size:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes}

\newcommand{\chainlabel}[2]{\path [<-, draw, shorten >=10pt] (#1) |- node [at end] {#2} ++(-1,1);}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, rectangle split horizontal,minimum height=14pt}, node distance=1em, start chain,
 every join/.style={->, shorten <=-4.5pt}]

 \node[draw, on chain, join] { 1  };
 \node[draw, on chain, join] { 7  };
 \node[draw, on chain, join] { 5  };
 \node[draw, on chain, join] { 2  };
 \node[draw, on chain, join] {};
\chainlabel{chain-1.one north}{head};
\end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh. How stupid of me. I had to stare at the code to figure out the mistake. How could I miss the slash in the command definition!