# doubly linked list tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to draw two doubly linked lists and I know that I can use the tikz package. But I don't know how to. Could anyone show an example code piece for the following doubly linked list?

I found some questions that are related to drawing doubly linked lists, e.g., [How should I draw a singly/double linked list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19286/how-should-i-draw-a-singly-double-linked-list). But I don't how to draw the "..." in the figure.

[image]

Comment: Welcome! There's nothing to say that you 'should' use TikZ. You could do it in TikZ, although it is arguably overkill.

Comment: Don't use tikz. Embrace SVG. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/how-to-include-svg-diagrams-in-latex#2107

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arguably overkill, but here's a version using the TikZ libraries `shapes.multipart`, `chains` and `positioning`:

```
\documentclass[border=20pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,chains, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      double link/.style n args=2{% page 726
        on chain,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split horizontal,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        draw,
        anchor=center,
        text height=1.5ex,
        node contents={#1\nodepart{two}#2},
      },
      start chain=going right,
    ]
    \node [on chain] {$\phi$};
    \node [join={by <-}, double link={a}{b}];
    \node [join={by <->}, double link={c}{d}];
    \node (a) [join={by <->}, double link={e}{f}];
    \node (b) [on chain, right=2.5pt of a.east] {$\cdots$};
    \node [double link={y}{z}, right=2.5pt of b.east];
    \node [join={by ->}, on chain] {$\phi$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: double trouble]

## EDIT

In response to [the comment asking about the addition of arcs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288362/doubly-linked-list-tikz/288370#comment697606_288370), there are various options. Here are 4 different arcs in various colours for ease of identification. [To please egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288362/doubly-linked-list-tikz/288370#comment697619_288370), I assume that the thing which I read as the Greek letter *phi* is, in fact, intended to be an empty set.

```
\documentclass[border=20pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,chains, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      double link/.style n args=2{% page 726
        on chain,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split horizontal,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        draw,
        anchor=center,
        text height=1.5ex,
        node contents={#1\nodepart{two}#2},
      },
      start chain=going right,
    ]
    \node [on chain] {$\emptyset$};
    \node (c) [join={by <-}, double link={a}{b}];
    \node [join={by <->}, double link={c}{d}];
    \node (a) [join={by <->}, double link={e}{f}];
    \node (b) [on chain, right=2.5pt of a.east] {$\cdots$};
    \node [join={with c by <->, bend right, draw=blue}, join={with c by <->, bend left, draw=green}, join={with c by <->, out=90, in=90, draw=red}, join={with c by <->, out=-135, in=-45, draw=magenta}, double link={y}{z}, right=2.5pt of b.east];
    \node [join={by ->}, on chain] {$\emptyset$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: arcs of various kinds]

Comment: Thanks a lot! By the way, is it possible to create an arc between {a, b} and {y, z} ?

Comment: `\emptyset \neq \phi`

Comment: @egreg I just went by the drawing. I guess I'm much more likely to see phi than an empty set symbol. Since I never read anything including the latter, but frequently read stuff including the former, I guess I assume the former is intended in case of ambiguity.

Comment: @addddddc Please see edit. Also, if the symbol at the ends is supposed to be an empty set, you shouldn't use `\phi`. On the other hand, if it is supposed to be the Greek letter *phi*, then you should use `\phi`. Horses for courses, as they say ;).

Comment: (+1) @cfr, with this additional request, your solution is not "overkill" solution anymore :-), actually it is the most rational!

Comment: @Zarko True. But it was overkill *qua* answer to the original question ;).

Answer (score 13):

I've found one useful [github repository](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples) with [example](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/tree/master/tikz/doubly-linked-list) of doubly linked list in tikz. You can inspire in this.

Code of the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.multipart,chains,arrows,positioning}

\tikzset{
    squarecross/.style={
        draw, rectangle,minimum size=18pt, fill=orange!80,
        inner sep=0pt, text=black,
        path picture = {
            \draw[black]
            (path picture bounding box.north west) --
            (path picture bounding box.south east)
            (path picture bounding box.south west) --
            (path picture bounding box.north east);
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        list/.style={
            very thick, rectangle split,
            rectangle split parts=3, draw,
            rectangle split horizontal, minimum size=18pt,
            inner sep=5pt, text=black,
            rectangle split part fill={blue!20, red!20, blue!20}
        },
        ->, start chain, very thick
      ]

  \node[list,on chain] (A) {\nodepart{second} 12};
  \node[list,on chain] (B) {\nodepart{second} 99};
  \node[list,on chain] (C) {\nodepart{second} 37};

  \node[squarecross]   (D) [right=of C] {};
  \node[squarecross]   (E) [left= of A] {};

  \path[*->] let \p1 = (A.three), \p2 = (A.center) in (\x1,\y2) edge [bend left] ($(B.one)+(0,0.2)$);
  \path[*->] let \p1 = (B.three), \p2 = (B.center) in (\x1,\y2) edge [bend left] ($(C.one)+(0,0.2)$);
  \draw[*->] let \p1 = (C.three), \p2 = (C.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (D);

  \draw[*->] ($(A.one)+(0.2,0.1)$) -- (E);
  \path[*->] ($(B.one)+(0.1,0.1)$) edge [bend left] ($(A.three)+(0,-0.05)$);
  \path[*->] ($(C.one)+(0.1,0.1)$) edge [bend left] ($(B.three)+(0,-0.05)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Link only answer are not really useful since the link may vanish ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry. Next time better.

Answer (score 9):

TikZ-free suggestion.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\boxlist[2]{\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline #1 & #2 \\ \hline \end{array}}
\begin{document}
\[
\phi \leftarrow
\boxlist{a}{b}
\leftrightarrow
\boxlist{c}{d}
\leftrightarrow
\boxlist{e}{f}
\leftrightarrow
\cdots
\leftrightarrow
\boxlist{x}{y}
\rightarrow \phi
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

A short example with `tikz-cd` and some TikZ for drawing the node border.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand\tkkz[2]{%
  \tikz{\node[draw, inner sep=2pt, minimum width=8mm,outer sep=0, text height=1.5ex, text depth=.3ex, append after command={\pgfextra{\draw (\tikzlastnode.north)--(\tikzlastnode.south);}}](a){#1~~#2}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
\varnothing \arrow[r,to-] & 
  \tkkz{a}{b} \arrow[r,to-to]&
  \tkkz{c}{d} \arrow[r,to-to]&
  \tkkz{e}{f} \arrow[r,to-to]&
  \cdots \arrow[r,to-] &
  \tkkz{y}{z} \arrow[r] &
\varnothing
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

---

### Curved arrows

To draw a curved arrow, just do either of these commands:

```
\arrow[rrrr, bend left=90]
or
\arrow[rrrr, out=90,in=90]
```

Each `r` tells the arrow to advance of a cell to the right, since `tikz-cd` is basically a matrix of nodes (similar to a tabular). To draw the arrow below, just invert the commands like this:

```
\arrow[rrrr, bend right=90]
or
\arrow[rrrr, out=-90,in=-90]
```

With either of those commands to draw the arrow above you get:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\LA\leftarrow  \let\RA\rightarrow \let\LRA\leftrightarrow
\def\BOX(#1,#2){\tabular{|c|c|}\hline\strut#1&#2\\\hline\endtabular}

\begin{document}

 $\thickmuskip=0mu\emptyset\,
  \LA\BOX(a,b)\LRA\BOX(c,d)\LRA\BOX(e,f)\LRA\cdots\LA\BOX(y,z)\RA\,
  \emptyset$ 

\end{document}
```

If you want the a,b,... in italic use `\array` instead of  `\tabular`

[image]