# Plot nodes of a list in LaTeX with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Which is the best way to reproduce something like that in tikzpicture?

[image]

Comment: some ideas here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288362/doubly-linked-list-tikz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The code below defines two commands.

```
\pointer[optional for position, label, ...]{name}{node pointed to}
\element[optional for position, label, ...]{name}{data}{node pointed to}
```

An empty `node pointed to` corresponds to the null pointer.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,shadows}
\usepackage{xifthen}
% definitions for list
\newcommand\boxsize{6mm}
\tikzset
  {cell/.style=
    {inner sep=0pt,minimum width=\boxsize,minimum height=\boxsize,
     drop shadow,fill=white},
   ptr/.style={Circle-stealth,shorten <=-1.5pt}
  }
\newcommand\pointer[3][]%
  {\node[draw,cell,#1] (#2) {};
   \ifthenelse{\isempty{#3}}%
     {\draw (#2.south west)--(#2.north east);}%
     {\draw[ptr] (#2.center)--(#3);}
  }
\newcommand\element[4][]%
  {\node[draw,cell,#1] (#2) {#3};
   \node[draw,cell,xshift=\boxsize] (#2ptr) at (#2) {};
   \ifthenelse{\isempty{#4}}%
     {\draw (#2ptr.south west)--(#2ptr.north east);}%
     {\draw[ptr] (#2ptr.center)--(#4);}
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \element{e1}{10}{}
  \element[left=of e1]{e2}{20}{e1}
  \element[left=of e2]{e3}{40}{e2}
  \element[left=of e3]{e4}{30}{e3}
  \pointer[left=5mm of e4,label=left:list]{list}{e4}
  \pointer[above=5mm of e4,label=above:cur]{cur}{e4}
  \pointer[above=5mm of list,label=above:prev]{prev}{}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I copy the arrowhead that You use in this example?  \draw[->, >= ???] (OneNode) -- (AnotherNode); @gernot

Comment: @AndreaLeo You probably mean `stealth` ...