# Draw a hash table

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to draw a hash table. I find the following [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19288/178449) which draws a linked list. I modify the code a little bit, resulting in

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,positioning, calc,shapes.multipart,chains,arrows}
\tikzset{listnode/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
    draw, rectangle split horizontal}}
\tikzset{hashtable/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=7,
    draw, rectangle split}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.2, >=stealth, start chain]
  \node[hashtable,on chain, inner sep=8pt] (H) {};
  \node[listnode,on chain] (A) {$12$};
  \node[listnode,on chain] (B) {$99$};
  \node[listnode,on chain] (C) {$37$};
  \node[on chain,inner sep=2pt] (D) {$\emptyset$};
  \draw[*->] let \p1 = (H.center), \p2 = (H.two) in (\x1,\y2) -- (A);
  \draw[*->] let \p1 = (A.two), \p2 = (A.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (B);
  \draw[*->] let \p1 = (B.two), \p2 = (B.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (C);
  \draw[*->] let \p1 = (C.two), \p2 = (C.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (D);
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

The code generates the following figure:

[image]

There are some points that I do not know how to fix:

1. The list nodes do not appear in the same line as the corresponding hash table slot.
2. I do not know how to adjust the arrow length.

Comment: Take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24305/1952

Comment: @JouleV I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code for the original image (you can find it by looking at the [revisions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/483974/revisions) of this question). I don't use `chain` as I don't have much experience with it.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,positioning,arrows,calc}
\tikzset{
    listnode/.style={
        rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2,draw,rectangle split horizontal,fill=blue!20
    },
    startnode/.style={
        draw,minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=.75cm
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.2, >=stealth]
\node[startnode] (t0) {$T[0]$};
\node[startnode,below=0pt of t0] (t1) {$T[1]$};
\node[startnode,below=0pt of t1] (t2) {$T[2]$};
\node[listnode,right=of t0] (3) {3};
\node[listnode,right=of t1] (1) {1};
\node[listnode,right=.5cm of 1] (7) {7};
\node[listnode,right=of t2] (2) {2};
\node[listnode,right=.5cm of 2] (5) {5};
\node[listnode,right=.5cm of 5] (8) {8};
\node[right=.5cm of 3] (3x) {$\varnothing$};
\node[right=.5cm of 7] (7x) {$\varnothing$};
\node[right=.5cm of 8] (8x) {$\varnothing$};
\draw[*->] let \p1 = (3.two), \p2 = (3.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (3x);
\draw[*->] let \p1 = (1.two), \p2 = (1.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (7);
\draw[*->] let \p1 = (7.two), \p2 = (7.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (7x);
\draw[*->] let \p1 = (2.two), \p2 = (2.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (5);
\draw[*->] let \p1 = (5.two), \p2 = (5.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (8);
\draw[*->] let \p1 = (8.two), \p2 = (8.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (8x);
\draw[->] (t0) edge (3) (t1) edge (1) (t2) edge (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As for the second diagram, finding the center anchor of `H.two` is a bit tricky.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,positioning, calc,shapes.multipart,chains,arrows}
\tikzset{listnode/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
    draw, rectangle split horizontal}}
\tikzset{hashtable/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=7,
    draw, rectangle split}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.2, >=stealth, start chain]
  \node[hashtable,inner sep=8pt] (H) {};
  \coordinate (x) at ($(H.text split)!.5!(H.two split)$);
  \node[listnode,on chain] (A) at ($(x)+(10,0)$) {$12$};
  \node[listnode,on chain] (B) {$99$};
  \node[listnode,on chain] (C) {$37$};
  \node[on chain,inner sep=2pt] (D) {$\varnothing$};
  \draw[->] (x) -- (A);
  \fill (x) circle (12.5pt); % I'm not sure what number to add here
  \draw[*->] let \p1 = (A.two), \p2 = (A.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (B);
  \draw[*->] let \p1 = (B.two), \p2 = (B.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (C);
  \draw[*->] let \p1 = (C.two), \p2 = (C.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to adjust the size of the "filled circle" in "*->".

Comment: @Matteo You can do as my first arrow: use `->` and then draw the circle manually.

Answer (score 2):

the list nodes are relatively positioned from `H.two east`, used are orthogonal coordinates for positioning of the arrows' starts and nodes styles are slightly modified. from `tikz` libraries are present only used ones:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\tikzset{hashtable/.style = {rectangle split,
                             rectangle split parts=7,
                             draw, inner sep=8pt},
         listnode/.style = {rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal,
                            rectangle split parts=2,
                            draw, on chain},  % <---
every edge/.style = {draw, Circle-Stealth}    % <---
         }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0mm and 9mm,   % <---
  start chain = A going right  % <---
                        ] 
%
\node[hashtable] (H) {};
\node[listnode, right=of H.two east] {$12$};    % <---, A-1
\node[listnode] {$99$};
\node[listnode] {$37$};
\node[on chain] {$\varnothing$};                % A-4
%
\draw   (H.two |- H.two east)       edge (A-1)  % <---
        (A-1.two |- A-1.two east)   edge (A-2)
        (A-2.two |- A-2.two east)   edge (A-3)
        (A-3.two |- A-2.two east)   edge (A-4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use relative positioning to place nodes accordingly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,positioning, calc,shapes.multipart,chains,arrows}
\tikzset{listnode/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
    draw, rectangle split horizontal}}
\tikzset{hashtable/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=7,
    draw, rectangle split}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.2, >=stealth, start chain]
  \node[hashtable,on chain, inner sep=8pt] (H) {};
  \node[listnode,on chain,above right=-1.4cm and 0.7cm of H] (A) {$12$};
  \node[listnode,on chain] (B) {$99$};
  \node[listnode,on chain] (C) {$37$};
  \node[on chain,inner sep=2pt] (D) {$\emptyset$};
  \draw[*->] let \p1 = (H.center), \p2 = (H.two) in (\x1,\y2) -- (A.west);
  \draw[*->] let \p1 = (A.two), \p2 = (A.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (B.west);
  \draw[*->] let \p1 = (B.two), \p2 = (B.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (C.west);
  \draw[*->] let \p1 = (C.two), \p2 = (C.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (D);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Regarding the arrow length, they depend on the node distance. If distance between two connecting nodes is more, the arrow length will be more.

[image]

Comment: It is clearly preferable to make the starting point at the center.

Comment: @JouleV I am trying that. But not sure now to do that. H.two is not located at the center

Comment: It is the midpoint of segment joining `H.text split` and `H.two split`. Look at my answer and at page 796 of the Ti*k*Z - PGF manual.