# TiKz figure getting cutting off due to its size

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting

I have a paper divided into 2 columns and I am "drawing" on the second column, I am trying to create a linked list there using the code given here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19288/233406 however, my linked list is too big and getting cut off, how can I solve this?

Minimum reproducible example:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.multipart,chains,arrows}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\raggedbottom
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

\title{test\\}


\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
dsfvdsfdsdsfdsfsd fsddsfvdsfdsdsfdsfsdfsddsfvdsfds dsfdsfsdfsddsfvdsfdsdsfdsfsdfsddsf vdsfdsdsfdsfsdfsddsfvdsf dsdsfdsfsdfsddsfvdsfdsdsfdsfsdfsddsfvdsfdsdsf dsfsdfsddsfvdsfdsdsfdsfsdfsddsf vdsfdsdsfdsfsdfsddsfvds fdsdsfdsfsdfsddsfvdsfdsdsfdsfsdfsd dsfvdsfdsdsfdsfsdfsddsfv dsfdsdsfdsfsdfsddsfvd sfdsdsfdsfsdfsddsfvdsfdsdsfdsfs dfsddsfvdsfdsdsf dsfsdf sddsfvdsfdsdsfdsfsdfs ddsfvdsf dsdsfdsfsdfsddsfvd sfdsdsfdsfsdfsdds fvdsfdsdsfdsfsdfsdddsfvdsfdsdsfdsfsdfsddsf vdsfdsdsfdsfsdf  sddsfvdsfdsdsfdsfsdfsddsfvds fdsdsfdsfsdfsddsfvd sfdsdsfdsfsdfsd dsfvds fdsdsfdsfsdfsddsfvdsfdsdsfdsfsdfs ddsfvdsfdsdsfdsfsdfsddsfvdsfdsdsfdsfsd fsddsfvdsfdsdsfdsfs dfsddsfvdsfds dsfdsfsdf sddsfvdsfdsdsfdsfsdfsdsfvdsfdsdsfds fsdfsddsfv dsfdsdsfdsfs dfsddsfvds fdsdsfdsf   sdfsddsfvdsfdsdsfdsfsdfsddsfvdsfdsdsfdsfsdfsd
\end{abstract}



\section{Introduction}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}[list/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
    draw, rectangle split horizontal}, >=stealth, start chain]
  \node[list,on chain] (A) {$w(B,4,1)$};
  \node[list,on chain] (B) {$r_3(B,4)$};
  \node[list,on chain] (C) {$r_3(B,4)$};
  \node[list,on chain] (D) {$w_3(B,4,6)$};
  \node[list,on chain] (E) {$r_4.fog.2(B,6)$};
  \node[on chain,draw,inner sep=6pt] (F) {};
  \draw (F.north east) -- (F.south west);
  \draw (F.north west) -- (F.south east);
  \draw[*->] let \p1 = (A.two), \p2 = (A.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (B);
  \draw[*->] let \p1 = (B.two), \p2 = (B.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (C);
    \draw[*->] let \p1 = (C.two), \p2 = (C.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (D);
      \draw[*->] let \p1 = (D.two), \p2 = (D.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (E);
        \draw[*->] let \p1 = (E.two), \p2 = (E.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (F);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Linked list corresponding to the $Fog.1$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here the list is on the first column so it just passes to the second one but in the original document it is in the second column which just makes it cut
Picture of what is happening:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated. I don't mind continuing the linked list on multiple lines/rows as long as it is clear, I don't necessarily want to fit it all in the same space as that might be unplausible.

Comment: Please extend your code snippet to complete small document which reproduce your problem. We need t know, wow wide is your text area on page. Try to use smaller font size ...

Comment: @Zarko done. also changing font isn't an option as certain requirements are demanded including the font size I am using,

Comment: You could rotate the image 90^\circ.  You might even use wrapfig, although squeezing text into a tiny space looks bad.

Comment: thanks @JohnKormylo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your figure is too large to stay on one column only and if you scale it it becomes unreadable.

You `figure*` environment to print it on two columns.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}% <--- for testing purpose only
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[3]% <--- for testing purpose only
\begin{figure*}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[list/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
    draw, rectangle split horizontal}, >=stealth, start chain]
  \node[list,on chain] (A) {$w(B,4,1)$};
  \node[list,on chain] (B) {$r_3(B,4)$};
  \node[list,on chain] (C) {$r_3(B,4)$};
  \node[list,on chain] (D) {$w_3(B,4,6)$};
  \node[list,on chain] (E) {$r_4.fog.2(B,6)$};
  \node[on chain,draw,inner sep=6pt] (F) {};
  \draw (F.north east) -- (F.south west);
  \draw (F.north west) -- (F.south east);
  \draw[Circle->] let \p1 = (A.two), \p2 = (A.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (B);
  \draw[Circle->] let \p1 = (B.two), \p2 = (B.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (C);
    \draw[Circle->] let \p1 = (C.two), \p2 = (C.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (D);
      \draw[Circle->] let \p1 = (D.two), \p2 = (D.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (E);
        \draw[Circle->] let \p1 = (E.two), \p2 = (E.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (F);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Linked list corresponding to the $Fog.1$}
\end{figure*}
\blindtext[7]% <--- for testing purpose only
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you would like to scale it:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}% <--- for testing purpose only
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[3]% <--- for testing purpose only
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
\scalebox{.47}{\begin{tikzpicture}[list/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
    draw, rectangle split horizontal}, >=stealth, start chain]
  \node[list,on chain] (A) {$w(B,4,1)$};
  \node[list,on chain] (B) {$r_3(B,4)$};
  \node[list,on chain] (C) {$r_3(B,4)$};
  \node[list,on chain] (D) {$w_3(B,4,6)$};
  \node[list,on chain] (E) {$r_4.fog.2(B,6)$};
  \node[on chain,draw,inner sep=6pt] (F) {};
  \draw (F.north east) -- (F.south west);
  \draw (F.north west) -- (F.south east);
  \draw[Circle->] let \p1 = (A.two), \p2 = (A.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (B);
  \draw[Circle->] let \p1 = (B.two), \p2 = (B.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (C);
    \draw[Circle->] let \p1 = (C.two), \p2 = (C.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (D);
      \draw[Circle->] let \p1 = (D.two), \p2 = (D.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (E);
        \draw[Circle->] let \p1 = (E.two), \p2 = (E.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (F);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{Linked list corresponding to the $Fog.1$}
\end{figure}
\blindtext[7]% <--- for testing purpose only
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't put it two columns, is there a way to make it on one?

Comment: @Sergio You can, see my edit, but it is unreadable, in my opinion.

Comment: thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Sergio You're welcome!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Done, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Mostly off-topic, however it may be useful ...

Your image is to wide that can be for in one column. Consequently, for image you should use `figure*` float. In cases, that you like image on the bottom of the same page, use `stfloats` package.

If this is not satisfactory, i.e. that image should be somewhere on a middle of the page, use `cute` package:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{capt-of}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{strip}
    \centering
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0mm and 6mm,
  start chain = A going right,
  list/.style = {rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
                 rectangle split horizontal, draw, inner sep=3.2pt}, 
   mlt/.style = {draw, minimum size=1em,
                 append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
                  \draw  (\LN.north west) -- (\LN.south east)
                        (\LN.south west) -- (\LN.north east);
                                     }}, 
                node contents={}},
   arr/.style = {{Circle[length=2mm, sep=0pt -2]}-Stealth}, 
                    ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={list, on chain}]
\node   {$w(B,4,1)$};           % A-1
\node   {$r_3(B,4)$};
\node   {$r_3(B,4)$};
\node   {$w_3(B,4,6)$};
\node   {$r_4.\mathit{fog}.2(B,6)$};     % A-5
    \end{scope}
\node[mlt, on chain] (A-6) {};
% arrows
\foreach \i [count=\j from 2] in {1,...,5}
    \draw[arr] (A-\i.two |- A-\i.east) -- (A-\j);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Linked list corresponding to the $Fog.1$}
\end{strip}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\lipsum[2-7]
\end{document}
```

[image]